# Trouble aligning TextView and Checkbox in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-styles, android-checkbox

I have a linear layout that contains a textview and checkbox.

```
 <LinearLayout style="@style/linearLayoutStyleNoBgColor" >
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/useFollowupDate"
         style="@style/textFieldStyleType1WithCheckbox" />

     <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/checkFollowDate"
         style="@style/checkboxStyleType1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And the styles are:

```
<style name="linearLayoutStyleNoBgColor">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:weightSum">1.0</item>
</style>


<style name="textFieldStyleType1WithCheckbox" parent="@style/textFieldStyleType1">
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.30</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="checkboxStyleType1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.70</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right|end</item>
</style>
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
TextView                |     checkbox
(30%percent screen)     |     (to the right)
```

But I am getting now is

```
TextView            | checkbox
(30%percent screen) | (left aligned)
```

Where am I gone wrong?

Comment: have you tried adding margins to the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gravity` and `layout_gravity` properties at proper places;

This might be useful : **http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/**

Comment: Could you walk me through my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to align them aptly then you can use relative layout. make check box to the right of the textview

```
<CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/checkFollowDate"
         style="@style/checkboxStyleType1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/useFollowupDate"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `android:gravity` to `android:layout_gravity` for `checkboxStyleType1`

Answer (score 0):

Styles.xml

```
<style name="linearLayoutStyleNoBgColor">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:weightSum">1.0</item>
</style>

<style name="textFieldStyleType1WithCheckbox">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="checkboxStyleType1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right|end</item>
</style>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/linearLayoutStyleNoBgColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/useFollowupDate"
        style="@style/textFieldStyleType1WithCheckbox"
        android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkFollowDate"
        style="@style/checkboxStyleType1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="checkbox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this will wok! however, I need 30:70 ratio on the screen. Please check the question!